# Redirect [R=301] ends next iterations in .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this simple .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^foo3$ foo2
RewriteRule ^foo2$ foo1
RewriteRule ^foo1$ index.php
```

When i type the url `https://localhost/foo3` it follows de rewrite "chain" and ends into index.php. That's ok.

But for this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^foo3$ foo2 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^foo2$ foo1
RewriteRule ^foo1$ index.php
```

i was expecting it to cascade down to index.php anyway (ignoring the redirect) but the browser makes the 301 redirect to `https://localhost/foo2` first (browser reflects that url) and then .htaccess "continues" from there down to index.php.

Does a `R=301` act like an `[END]` directive in this situation somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a `R=301` act like an `[END]` directive in this situation somehow?

No `END` is not in effect but `L` (last) is. Please understand `END` behaves differently from `L`.

Hence Apache sends a `301` to browser and browser does a full redirect, then it sends `/foo2` again to web server and then 2nd and 3rd rules are executed.

---

**Update:**

Thanks to comment from @MrWhite below, I have run this test while keeping rewrite logs in `trace4`.

Config to enable rewrite logging:

```
LogLevel info rewrite:trace4
```

And here are additional logs that came in my Apache error logs. Please note that my local host name is `localhost` and my `DocumentRoot` is `/www/root`.

**Step:** Applying rule #1, URI is `/foo3`:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /www/root/foo3 -> foo3
applying pattern '^foo3$' to uri 'foo3'
rewrite 'foo3' -> 'foo2'
add per-dir prefix: foo2 -> /www/root/foo2
explicitly forcing redirect with http://localhost/www/root/foo2
```

**Step:** Applying rule #2, URI is `http://localhost/www/root/foo2` (Note that your `RewriteBase /` hasn't come into effect yet):

```
applying pattern '^foo2$' to uri 'http://localhost/www/root/foo2'
```

**Step:** Applying rule #3, URI is `http://localhost/www/root/foo2`:

```
applying pattern '^foo1$' to uri 'http://localhost/www/root/foo2'
```

**Step:** Applying external redirect `301` by stripping `DocumentRoot` with your `RewriteBase` value:

```
trying to replace prefix /www/root/ with /
add subst prefix: foo2 -> foo2
escaping http://localhost/foo2 for redirect
redirect to http://localhost/foo2 [REDIRECT/301]
```

**Step:** Applying rule #1, URI is `/foo2`:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /www/root/foo2 -> foo2
applying pattern '^foo3$' to uri 'foo2'
```

**Step:** Applying rule #2, URI is `/foo2`:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /www/root/foo2 -> foo2
applying pattern '^foo2$' to uri 'foo2'
rewrite 'foo2' -> 'foo1'
```

**Step:** Applying rule #3, URI is `/foo1`:

```
add per-dir prefix: foo1 -> /www/root/foo1
strip per-dir prefix: /www/root/foo1 -> foo1
applying pattern '^foo1$' to uri 'foo1'
rewrite 'foo1' -> 'index.php'
```

**Step:** Internal rewrite to `/index.php`:

```
add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /www/root/index.php
trying to replace prefix /www/root/ with /
add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

**Step:** Applying rule #1, URI is `/index.php`:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /www/root/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^foo3$' to uri 'index.php'
```

**Step:** Applying rule #2, URI is `/index.php`:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /www/root/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^foo2$' to uri 'index.php'
```

**Step:** Applying rule #3, URI is `/index.php`:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /www/root/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^foo1$' to uri 'index.php'
```

**Step:** Stop rule processing, URI is `/index.php`:

```
pass through /www/root/index.php
```

I have added detailed trace logging and my `step` comment above to show how `L` is a *side effect* where rule processing is not completely stopped. However the fact `mod_rewrite` engines attempts to apply remaining rules on a URI **that is invalid** i.e. `http://localhost/www/root/foo2` those rules will not execute and full redirect will be the outcome.

Comment: But why is it sending the 301? Why is it not processing the 2nd and 3rd rules in the first iteration, "overwriting" the first rule (as in the first example)?

Comment: If i understand *.ht* execution correctly, when `L` flag is encountered and a rewrite happened, *.ht* is rerun from the start with that rewrite as the "requested uri".
If that is correct, when `R=301` (plus the implicit `L`) is evaluated, no more rules are processed and a 2nd iteration should start with `foo2` as the input. In that iteration 2nd rule will apply followed by the 
1st rule (no `L` in 2nd rule). We reached EOF and a rewrite happened so a 3rd iteration starts with `index.php` as input. No rewrites happen so `index.php` should be the resource to get. Is this accurate?

Comment: You have put it really well, It is absolutely correct.

Comment: But why is the `301` redirect issued then? Why is it not overwritten by the 2nd and 3rd iterations of *.ht*?

Comment: So when a `R=301` rewrite applies, no more rules are evaluated on that loop (because of implicit `L`), no new loops of *.ht* are started (as expected because a rewrite happened), and the redirect is issued to the browser?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Since a ful redirect with `R` is outcome of first run apache has to send that status back to browser. When browser sends next request with new URL i.e. `/foo2` it processes .htaccess again from top.

Comment: "When you use `R` flag then `L` is implicit" - This isn't strictly true. The `L` flag is only implied for non-3xx response codes. In the case above, processing _does_ continue, except the rule that follows simply doesn't match because the `R=301` flag causes the rewrite engine to construct an absolute URL (of sorts) which is passed on to the next rule. Remove the start anchor (`^`) on the 2nd rule and it does match, ultimately resulting in a bit of a malformed response... it internally rewrites to `index.php` but sends a 301 response code and no `Location` header (so no redirect).

Comment: Thanks so much @MrWhite for your detailed comment. You are right that `L` is not explicit after 1st rule. But since `mod_rewrite` attempts to apply further rules on an invalid URI, remaining rules are not applied. tI have added detailed trace logs with my comments above in my answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I have tried to see the rewrite logs in my wamp installation but no log is generated in the apache error file. I have put the line `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace4` in httpd.conf, enabled `mod_log_config.so`, `mod_log_debug.so` and `mod_log_forensic.so` modules (i think it's needed too) and restarted Apache but no log is generated.

Comment: Please check official docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging